# Writing the pipleline, which lists the user's last messages for the user_chats collection we keep in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, nosql

```
{
  "_id": "654f4d7cbb027c35a0b90529",
  "msg": "test message",
  "createdat": {
    "$date": "2023-11-11T09:46:41.872Z"
  },
  "dateseen": {
    "$date": "2023-11-11T09:55:56.596Z"
  },
  "fromid": "eb78a1f79938f5eb193b63fc13b3250",
  "toid": "7b987d98718041abb3b9a85b5c96214a",
  "deleted1": false,
  "deleted1at": null,
  "deleted2": false,
  "deleted2at": null,
  "type": 1
}
```

have a query where I keep data in the above format. I want to get the user's messaging and last messages by sending userId. I created a pipeline for this in Golang, but the optimization is not working, messages are not coming in some cases, etc.

Thanks

The pipeline I prepared;

```
pipeline := []bson.M{
{
"$sort": bson.M{"createdat": -1},
},
{
"$match": bson.M{
"$or": []bson.M{
{"fromid": userID, "deleted1": false},
{"toid": userID, "deleted2": false},
},
},
},
{
"$group": bson.M{
"_id": bson.M{"$cond": []interface{}{bson.M{"$ne": []interface{}{"$toid", userID}}, "$toid", "$ fromid"}},
"lastMessage": bson.M{"$first": "$$ROOT"},
"unseenCount": bson.M{
"$sum": bson.M{
"$cond": []interface{}{
bson.M{"$and": []interface{}{
bson.M{"$eq": []interface{}{"$toid", userID}},
bson.M{"$eq": []interface{}{"$dateseen", nil}},
}},
one,
0,
},
},
},
},
},
{
"$sort": bson.M{"createdat": -1},
},
{
"$replaceRoot": bson.M{
"newRoot": bson.M{
"$mergeObjects": []interface{}{
"$lastMessage",
bson.M{"unSeenMsgCount": "$unseenCount"},
},
},
},
},
{
"$group": bson.M{
"_id": "$toid",
"lastMessage": bson.M{
"$first": "$$ROOT",
},
},
},
{
"$sort": bson.M{"createdat": -1},
},
{
"$replaceRoot": bson.M{
"newRoot": "$lastMessage",
},
},
{
"$sort": bson.M{"createdat": -1},
},
{
"$skip": offset,
},
{
"$limit": limit,
},
}

cursor, err := r.collection.Collection("user_chats").Aggregate(context.Background(), pipeline)
if err != nil {
return nil, err
}
```

The current problem is that sometimes the userId I send does not appear in the message list unless the last message belongs to him/her. I need a more optimized suggestion.

Comment: Can you please format your aggregation pipeline (i.e. with indention) or even better convert to mongosh syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not fully clear to me, however [$setWindowFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/) could be a starting point:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        { "fromid": userID, "deleted1": false },
        { "toid": userID, "deleted2": false }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$fromid",
      sortBy: { createdat: -1 },
      output: {
        messageRankFrom: { $denseRank: {} }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$toid",
      sortBy: { createdat: -1 },
      output: {
        messageRankTo: { $denseRank: {} }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { messageRankFrom: 1 },
        { messageRankTo: 1 }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3ZrkPDav60-)

Comment: Thanks for your help, my requirement is as follows; I am trying to show the last messaged people of the userID I sent, the last message with them and the number of unread messages with a limit offset. I had already posted my collection model, my aim was to make the listing in the DM box, unfortunately I could not run the query you sent :(